# Writing matrices as power series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, power-series, cayley-hamilton

I was reading a proof of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem [here](http://faculty.fairfield.edu/cbernhardt/cayleyhamilton.pdf), in which the author used matrices in power series. I found out that one can write

$$\left( \frac{1}{m} I + A \right)^{-1}$$

as a power series (the Neumann series) and that it converges under certain conditions. What I don't understand is why one can write $$\mbox{adj}(I-tA)$$ as a power series. I didn't find any information about writing matrices in general as power series and I didn't encounter anything like that before in my studies. Why

$$\mbox{adj}(I-tA) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty B_it^i$$

and, more generally, under what conditions can one write matrices as power series and how?

Comment: You must be careful: the author specifies that those are formal power series, thus he treats them as algebraic objects and hence can operate with them (loosely speaking) forgetting about convergence and so on. I unfortunately am too out of the subject in order to give you a good reference.

Comment: @b00nheT does this mean his proof is only correct in special cases?

Comment: No. The proof always works, but when the author writes "the inverse of $I-tA$ is always $\sum A^i t^i$'' he means that in an algebraic sense. That is to say: that is an object in the ring $M(n,n)[t]$ of formal power series over $M(n,n)$. If you multiply the two algebraically and add the terms you really get $I$ as a result, but the object $\sum A^it^i$ is not meant to be evaluated at $t=$something.
PS: i really am a little bit rusty on the subject. I am sure somebody can explain this in a more proper way.